# Configure a block view via block settings

Tags: views, blocks, users

I'm developing a website for a comprehensive but not professional user. He has the permissions to configure blocks (in order to tweak minor things like ordering or so).
Now I have a block view and I want to allow him to configure the number of displayed items for that block without giving him the permissions for view configuration in general.

Is there a way to put certain aspects of a block view configuration onto the configure block page or a similarly consistent way to achieve that?

(working on drupal 7 with views 3.10, btw.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Views UI: Edit Basic Settings](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_ui_basic) may meet your needs.

> "Views UI: Edit Basic Settings" places edit tabs on Views pages, similar to node pages, and allows users with the correct permission to modify their header, footer, title, empty text, or **number of items to display**. This module also provides a separate interface that displays a list of views. All Views are defined by you, so you can exclude certain Views.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!